# CSS z-index does not working in absolute div inside relative div

Tags: html, css, z-index

[image]

z-index does not working.
I have an process div(container)
And inside process div, there are links in a row.
And again, links are divide into progress_number div(large number)
and progress_text div(short description below large number).
And I put bars between each progress_number divs.

Here's html code

```
<div class="process">
    <a href="">
        <div class="process_number">1</div>
        <div class="process_text">text1</div>
    </a>
    <a href="">
        <div class="process_number">2</div>
        <div class="process_text">text2</div>
    </a>
    <a href="" class="process_selected">
        <div class="process_number">3</div>
        <div class="process_text">text3</div>
    </a>
    <a href="">
        <div class="process_number">4</div>
        <div class="process_text">text4</div>
    </a>
    <a href="">
        <div class="process_number">5</div>
        <div class="process_text">text5</div>
    </a>
</div>
```

And this is css code.

```
.process{
    width:100%;
    height:160px;
    border-bottom:1px solid #c4cdd2;
    margin-top:35px;
    z-index:;
}
.process a{
    text-align:center;
    text-decoration:none;
    display:inline-block;
    margin-left:186.5px;
    position: relative;
}
.process a:first-child{
    margin-left:50px;
}   
.process .process_number{
    height:75px;
    width:75px;
    font-size:47px;
    font-weight:bold;
    border: 1px solid #47a5d8;
    border-radius:100%;
    color: #47a5d8;
    background-color:#fff;
    text-align:center;
    line-height:170%;
    z-index:;
}   
.process .process_text{
    font-size:15px;
    font-weight:bold;
    color: #c4cdd2;
    margin-top:10px;
}
.process .process_number::before{
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    top:33px;
    right:55px;
    width:250px;
    height:10px;
    background-color:#47a5d8;
    z-index:1;
}
.process a:first-child .process_number::before{
    display:none;
}
.process_selected .process_number{
    color:#fff;
    background-color:#47a5d8;
}
.process_selected ~ a .process_number{
    color:#c4cdd2;
    background-color:#fff;
    border-color:#c4cdd2;
}
.process_selected ~ a .process_number::before{
    background-color:#c4cdd2;
} 
.process_selected .process_text{
    color:#47a5d8;
}
```

Now I want to hide the bar(.process_number::before) behind the large round bounded number(.process_number).
I've tried modifying z-index correctly, but every attempt to any element failed.
Give me some advice please.

Answer (score 0):

I saw that setting **z-index: -1** to **.process .process_number::before** just do it.

```css
.process{
    width:100%;
    height:160px;
    border-bottom:1px solid #c4cdd2;
    margin-top:35px;
    z-index:;
}
.process a{
    text-align:center;
    text-decoration:none;
    display:inline-block;
    margin-left:186.5px;
    position: relative;
}
.process a:first-child{
    margin-left:50px;
}   
.process .process_number{
    height:75px;
    width:75px;
    font-size:47px;
    font-weight:bold;
    border: 1px solid #47a5d8;
    border-radius:100%;
    color: #47a5d8;
    background-color:#fff;
    text-align:center;
    line-height:170%;
    z-index:;
}   
.process .process_text{
    font-size:15px;
    font-weight:bold;
    color: #c4cdd2;
    margin-top:10px;
}
.process .process_number::before{
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    top:33px;
    right:55px;
    width:250px;
    height:10px;
    background-color:#47a5d8;
    z-index:-1;
}
.process a:first-child .process_number::before{
    display:none;
}
.process_selected .process_number{
    color:#fff;
    background-color:#47a5d8;
}
.process_selected ~ a .process_number{
    color:#c4cdd2;
    background-color:#fff;
    border-color:#c4cdd2;
}
.process_selected ~ a .process_number::before{
    background-color:#c4cdd2;
} 
.process_selected .process_text{
    color:#47a5d8;
}
```

```html
<div class="process">
    <a href="">
        <div class="process_number">1</div>
        <div class="process_text">text1</div>
    </a>
    <a href="">
        <div class="process_number">2</div>
        <div class="process_text">text2</div>
    </a>
    <a href="" class="process_selected">
        <div class="process_number">3</div>
        <div class="process_text">text3</div>
    </a>
    <a href="">
        <div class="process_number">4</div>
        <div class="process_text">text4</div>
    </a>
    <a href="">
        <div class="process_number">5</div>
        <div class="process_text">text5</div>
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks to your advise, but did not working yet. z-index:-1 makes bars disappear. I think maybe bars coverd by wrapper(class .process). Whole page code is too much to discribe, but in short,  <div id="Container"> <div id="Main_Wrap"> <div class="center"> and <div class="process"> are nested  in layers. Is it cause of problem that too much nested div like this case?

Comment: You may want to check out this post http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/what-you-may-not-know-about-the-z-index-property--webdesign-16892
I will help you understand the z-index better

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding z-index of 1 to your `.process .process_number::before`
add `z-index:-1`, try below updated codes.

```css
.process{
    width:100%;
    height:160px;
    border-bottom:1px solid #c4cdd2;
    margin-top:35px;
}

.process a{
    text-align:center;
    text-decoration:none;
    position: relative;
    margin-left:100px;
    display:inline-block;
}
.process a:first-child{
    margin-left:0px;
}   
.process .process_number{
    height:75px;
    width:75px;
    font-size:47px;
    font-weight:bold;
    border: 1px solid #47a5d8;
    border-radius:100%;
    color: #47a5d8;
    background-color:#fff;
    text-align:center;
    line-height:170%;
    z-index:9;
}   
.process .process_text{
    font-size:15px;
    font-weight:bold;
    color: #c4cdd2;
    margin-top:10px;
}
.process .process_number::before{
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    top:33px;
    right:55px;
    width:200px;
    height:10px;
    background-color:#47a5d8;
    z-index:-1;
}
.process a:first-child .process_number::before{
    display:none;
}
.process_selected .process_number{
    color:#fff;
    background-color:#47a5d8;
}
.process_selected ~ a .process_number{
    color:#c4cdd2;
    background-color:#fff;
    border-color:#c4cdd2;
}
.process_selected ~ a .process_number::before{
    background-color:#c4cdd2;
} 
.process_selected .process_text{
    color:#47a5d8;
}
```

```html
<div class="process">
    <a href="">
        <div class="process_number">1</div>
        <div class="process_text">text1</div>
    </a>
    <a href="">
        <div class="process_number">2</div>
        <div class="process_text">text2</div>
    </a>
    <a href="" class="process_selected">
        <div class="process_number">3</div>
        <div class="process_text">text3</div>
    </a>
    <a href="">
        <div class="process_number">4</div>
        <div class="process_text">text4</div>
    </a>
    <a href="">
        <div class="process_number">5</div>
        <div class="process_text">text5</div>
    </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add `position: relative` (or absolute) to any class that has a z-index